# Finding the price of a product with sub-variables and giving it as a link?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have got a sheet.

Like This : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IZKQENWb9JOeVvjU3ioj6769PvHcRtXmo-urZZ8R3CQ/edit?usp=sharing

This list includes the products, the main features of the products and their prices according to these basic features.

What I want to do is; when they click on these essential features, they go to the price of their own feature. I don't want to do this manually one by one because there are too many products. I want to create it by writing a formula.

Anyone help this? Thank you :)

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are different applications and work differently - please remove the irrelevant tag/s from your question.

Comment: Which cells are features? What output do you expect?

Comment: Dear @SpencerBarnes if anyone do this in Excel, i can use it no problem.

Comment: Dear @Harun24hr "TYPE" Cells is feature. like as weight or length etc.